# Why can't I type or click into textarea?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to **HTML** and **CSS**, and I have some problems that I can't fix by myself.

My problem is that I can't type into my `textarea`, when I click on it nothing happens, also, I tried to put text ( "New Paste" ) above that, and I cant see it.
There is already questions on Stackoverflow about the `textarea` problem, but it didnt match to my problem.

- How can I change my `textarea` position to be under the "New Paste" text ?
- How can I fix my problem with `textarea` and write to it ?

```js
function saveTextAsFile() {
  var textToWrite = document.getElementById('textArea1').innerHTML;
  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  var fileNameToSaveAs = "MakePython.py";

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  if (window.webkitURL != null) {
    // Chrome allows the link to be clicked without actually adding it to the DOM.
    downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
  } else {
    // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM before it can be clicked.
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  }

  downloadLink.click();
}

var button = document.getElementById('SaveFile');
button.addEventListener('click', saveTextAsFile);

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
  // remove the link from the DOM
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightslategray
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 18px;
  background-color: teal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

#textAreaOne {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  resize: none;
  width: 950px;
  height: 750px;
}

#SaveFile {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

#SaveFile:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="text" href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="text" href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a class="text" href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<p style="color: black;"><b>New Paste</b></p>

<textarea id="textAreaOne"></textarea>
<button id="SaveFile" type="button" value="Save File">Save</button>
```

Comment: I can type in textarea? What browser do you use?

Comment: @ÖmürcanCengiz Google Chrome

Comment: Your textarea works. Even in the code snippet.

Comment: Yeah it is working @nakE

Comment: @ÖmürcanCengiz So why I can't see it ? And can you see the "New Paste" text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textArea id **textAreaOne** but you select the **textArea1**

```
var textToWrite = document.getElementById('textArea1').innerHTML;
```

`<textarea id="textAreaOne"></textarea>`

That's why when you click button nothing happens. To fix this handle true id
Also i would like say something about your HTML

- Give an static height your header which is ul in this example
- Use HTML5 tags like `<header>`, `<section>`
- Then let margin on top the section because your header is position absolute or fixed, so this is not effect to relative height.

For example:

````
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        header {
            position: absolute;
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
        }
        section {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    ...blabla
    </header>
    <section>
    ...blabla
    </section>
</body>```
````

Answer (score 3):

Changing the `position: fixed` to `sticky` fixes your 'New Paste' problem.

```js
function saveTextAsFile() {
  var textToWrite = document.getElementById('textArea1').innerHTML;
  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });
  var fileNameToSaveAs = "MakePython.py";

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  if (window.webkitURL != null) {
    // Chrome allows the link to be clicked without actually adding it to the DOM.
    downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
  } else {
    // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM before it can be clicked.
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  }

  downloadLink.click();
}

var button = document.getElementById('SaveFile');
button.addEventListener('click', saveTextAsFile);

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
  // remove the link from the DOM
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightslategray;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

.text {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 18px;
  background-color: teal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

#textAreaOne {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  resize: none;
  width: 950px;
  height: 750px;
}

#SaveFile {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

#SaveFile:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="text" href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="text" href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a class="text" href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<p style="color: black;"><b>New Paste</b></p>

<textarea id="textAreaOne"></textarea>
<button id="SaveFile" type="button" value="Save File">Save</button>
```

Like I said, your textarea just works fine.